# How to copy text from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Sometimes I want to copy a command from Powershell to paste in a document, or I want to copy the output? How can I select and copy text in Powershell?

At least I know a way how to paste a text (or a command) into Powershell: you just right-click on Powershell.

Comment: You may want to move non-SharePoint related answers to the more generic Stack Overflow site. I do appreciate you are probably using PowerShell in combination with SharePoint, but this questions doesn't belong here.

Comment: I agree. It is not a pure Sharepoint question.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just select the text in the console window and press enter or the right mouse button. That selected text ends up in your clipboard.

Note that this will only work if QuickEdit mode is enabled for the console window. If it is not, then either enable it in the console window properties (System menu → Properties → Options) or enter Mark mode via System menu → Edit → Mark (Alt+Space, E, K on an English Windows).

Comment: Using the shift key to highlight the text (text turns white) didn't work for me. I had to use the mouse to highlight the text (text turns orange)

Comment: How do I select all text in the window?

Answer (score 31):

Or send the output of your command directly to clipboard using clip.exe
For example,

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Test -recurse | Clip
```

Comment: a pipe with clip i a good alternative, too! Thank you!

Comment: This will not work with Unicode, though. In that case you can use `Set-Clipboard` from PSCX.

Comment: There IS a way to have `clip.exe` handle Unicode correctly: set PS's `$OutputEncoding` variable to BOM-less UTF-16 first, as follows: `$OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UnicodeEncoding($false, $false)`

Comment: This last trick is what I looked for coming here ! Thanks : )

Comment: And if you want to paste it, either Ctrl v or `get-clipboard`

Comment: @joey, I use powershell 5 with default config and kann use both cmdlets.

Comment: @Timo: `Set-Clipboard` is long-since included in PowerShell. Haven't installed PSCX in ages, but it was once handy, back in the PowerShell 2/3 days

Answer (score 11):

Go to the menubar, top left, **Edit**, **Select All**, **Copy**, *paste in notepad*

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Send Text in Clipboard to Application like Notepad (C# or Powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795360/send-text-in-clipboard-to-application-like-notepad-c-or-powershell). You will find some more tips. However, answer by @Wictor is probably the easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

`Set-Clipboard` is standard cmdlet as of Powershell v5.0. In some cases you should convert objects to text with `Out-String` before piping result to the clipboard:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows -recurse -depth 1 | Out-String -stream | Set-Clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

I've build my own out-clipboard funciton for this.

```
Function Out-Clipboard{
    param($Value,[switch]$PassThru) 
    begin {
            [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Windows.Forms")
        $tb = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
        $tb.Multiline = $true
        $pipeObjects = @()
    }
    process {
      $pipeObjects+=$_
    }
    end {
        if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Value)){
            $text=$null
            $pipeObjects | out-string -stream | %{$text = $text + $(if($text -ne $null){"`r`n"}) + $_}
            $tb.text = $text
        } 
        else {
            $tb.text = $value
        }
        $tb.SelectAll()
        $tb.Copy()
        if($PassThru){
            $pipeObjects
        }
        $tb.Dispose()
    }
}
```

Sample command line:

```
Get-Process | Out-Clipboard
```

Hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Your code doesn't work on my box: New-Object : Cannot find type [System.Windows.Forms.TextBox]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
At line:5 char:25
+         $tb = New-Object <<<<  System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:) [New-Object], PSArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Comment: If you check out http://pscx.codeplex.com/ , one of the functions provided by the community extensions is out-clipboard

Comment: It is very impressive, @CosmosKey! Thanks for mentioning pscx.codeplex.com, @Winfred!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the last command you typed to the clipboard, the following command is useful (especially for commands that span multiple lines):

```
(Get-History -Count 1).CommandLine | Set-Clipboard
```

If you want to repeat the last command, and copy its output to the clipboard, use:

```
Invoke-History | Set-Clipboard
```

Caveat: you should only do this for inexpensive and idempotent commands without any side-effects.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this may help someone. For Windows 10, the **Terminal** application offers an auto-copy option in **Settings > Interaction > Automatically copy selection to clipboard**.

To paste inside Powershell, you can use **Ctrl+V** or **Shift+Insert**, no need to use the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Did Windows 11 really remove the menu bar from Powershell?

Anyway, to select all, use **Ctrl+Shift+A**, and to copy and paste are both **Right Clicks**.